# Connecting to Private GKE cluster using 3rd party VPN

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, openvpn, google-cloud-networking, gke-networking

We have OpenVPN community edition VPN installed on our on-prim server and a private GKE cluster without public end point created in a GCP., Is there a possiblity we can connect to this Private cluster to run the kubectl commands from my local machine.,

FYI. I enabled the firewall rule by adding the public ip of the VPN on VPC., Its giving me :

```
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

despite running gcloud auth login "account" / gcloud cluster get-credentials....

Comment: Hi there! Take a look for to this approach [GKE private cluster with a bastion host](https://medium.com/google-cloud/gke-private-cluster-with-a-bastion-host-5480b44793a7) I think this may help you with your issue. Is not a VPN, but this approach removes the overhead of managing a VPN.

Comment: Thanks @ArmandoCuevas for the inputs., But we need it to managed through VPN., Thats mandatory.

Comment: Which command is giving you the error you listed above?  And can you provide a few more details about your VPN setup?

Comment: @GariSingh., We are using the pritunl VPN where in running any kubectl command like kubectl get pods/all is giving the error mentioned above..

Comment: Can you try running your `kubectl` commands with the `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` flag?  Want to see if it's actually connecting the the Kube API server.

Comment: It doesnt help much the output is of different node pool. despite doing `get-credentials` of the cluster intended. To be precise this is happening when connected with the VPN. If not connected to VPN its errors out as connection couldnt establish which is expected. @GariSingh

Comment: My guess is that somehow the VPN connecting/routing you to the wrong cluster.
If you run `kubectl cluster-info --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true` is the address returned for the control plane the one you expect?

Comment: Yes @GariSingh., Its giving me the intended cluster info

Comment: can you provide more information about you netowork infrastructure ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859568/access-a-node-port-service-in-a-private-gke-cluster-from-another-gke-private-clu/73567959#73567959